# Select all columns from one table and 1 column from another

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following query in linq:

```
(from creditCard in DbSet
join rank in base.dataContext.ProductVerticalRanks on creditCard.ProductVerticalReferenceId equals rank.ProductVerticalReferenceId
 where rank.ClientId == clientId
 orderby rank.PreferredOrder
 select creditCard)
 .Include(creditCard => creditCard.ProductVerticalCompany)
 .Include(creditCard => creditCard.Labels);
```

But now I have a new requirement, I need to add a column 'rank.PreferredOrder' from table 'rank' into the result, is there an easy way of doing this without making a massive 'select' statement, because there are around 20-30 fields in creditCard alone.

Comment: Your model is one to many right? One credit card to many ranks?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont have your model in front of me, so can't confirm this or not, but you can use an anonymous object like this:

```
from creditCard in DbSet
join rank in base.dataContext.ProductVerticalRanks on 
    creditCard.ProductVerticalReferenceId equals rank.ProductVerticalReferenceId into g
where rank.ClientId == clientId
orderby rank.PreferredOrder
select new {Card = creditCard, Ranks = g}
```

Comment: I guess I will have to do it in two steps then. Because this query is returned against this object: IQueryable<CreditCard> creditCardQuery = query...

Comment: No, it does not